# Virtuoso ISQL Result Dump Format

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso, sparqlwrapper

I am running following query on Virtuoso isql.

```
SPARQL 
CONSTRUCT
{
 ?infectee ?getInfectedBy ?infector
}

FROM <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/>

WHERE
{
  ?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram>.
  ?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infectee_pid> ?infectee.
  ?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infector_pid> ?infector.
  ?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_iteration> '0'^^xsd:decimal.
  BIND (iri('http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/getInfectedBy') as ?getInfectedBy)
 };
```

I want to dump result in "N-Triples" format. How can I do it in isql?

Comment: This option is at the bottum. There is "Raw Linked Data formats: CSV | RDF (N-Triples N3/Turtle JSON XML) | ODATA (Atom | JSON)". Please note that this question is product-related and such it shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: @Ivo **"Please note that this question is product-related and such it shouldn't be asked here."** it can still be asked here. Just because it's product related doesn't mean it's off topic.  Along how yu do something in MySQL vs. Postgres vs. SQL Server would be fine, too, and those are all product specific.

Answer (score 2):

Answered on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users) where [the question was also asked](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/35154898/)...

Dumping results in various formats can be done by using the

```
define output:format "{XX}"
```

pragma, so in your case it would be:

```
SQL> sparql define output:format "TURTLE" CONSTRUCT ...
```

Other possible formats are:

- `NICE_TTL`
- `RDF_XML`
- etc.

When using the ISQL client to fetch long texts, use the `set blobs on;` directive to avoid receiving a `data truncated` warning.

i.e.:

```
SQL> set blobs on;
SQL> sparql define output:format ...
```

For `CONSTRUCT`, the supported formats are:

`TRIG`, `TTL`, `JSON`, `JSON;TALIS`, `SOAP`, `RDF/XML`, `NT`, `RDFA;XHTML`, `JSON;RES`, `HTML;MICRODATA`, `HTML`, `JS`, `ATOM;XML`, `JSON;ODATA`, `XML`, `CXML;QRCODE`, `CXML`, `HTML;UL`, `HTML;TR`, `JSON;LD`, `CSV`, `TSV`, `NICE_TTL`, `HTML;NICE_MICRODATA`, `HTML;SCRIPT_LD_JSON`, `HTML;SCRIPT_TTL`, `HTML;NICE_TTL`

**Documentation links:**

- [Pragmas to control the type of the result](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#rdfsparqlimplementatioptragmasctr)
- [List of supported formats](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#rdfsparqlimplementatioptragmassfs)
- Examples:

  - [Example Dump arbitrary query result as N-Triples](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#anytimequeriessparqlex)
  - [Controlling SPARQL Output Data Types](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparql.html#rdfcontrollingsparqloutputtypes)

To get the result into a local file, the following should work:

1. insert the data into `XX.ttl` local file:

> `isql host:port dba pwd exec="set blobs on; sparql define output:format '"TURTLE"' construct {...} from <....> where {....}" > XX.ttl`

2. trim the first 9 lines so to have as content only the triples:

> `tail -n +9 XX.ttl > XX_new.ttl`